# Sending SMS using API using flowroute API

Tags: php, api, sms

I want to Send SMS using [flowroute](https://developer.flowroute.com/libraries/v2/) API. I want to use PHP or Laravel Framework. I didn't get any good tutorial about it.

Answer (score 0):

You know, that you just need to read and click a littlebit? The address you refered to, shows PHP-examples. On the target-github-page you can find the text "To work with the SDK, please read and follow the steps in the Flowroute PHP Library v2.". What is the problem?

Comment: I have read already and tried with their procedure but didn't make it work. I am searching a good tutorial

Comment: I think, you won't find it this way in stackoverflow, because this is a question for search engines. Just search for "flowroute examples". In this portal you should try to ask specific questions, that give you an answer to a your specific problem. In your case typical questions would be: What didn't work in your case? What errors did you get? a.s.o. And flowroute is responsible for mistakes in there tutorial. You can ask there too. AND they have a support chat (bot).